# How to detect and remove datetime from a paragraph in php

Tags: php

I have dynamic paragraph of string like thik :

> Rebel Wilson hits out on Twitter after Bauer Media appeal defamation
>   settlementImage:MediaPunch/REX/ShutterstockBy Gianluca Mezzofiore
>   **2017-10-09 10:29:36** UTC The battle is not over for Rebel Wilson.The Pitch Perfect star has to face another legal challenge as
>   Bauer Media is appealing against the multi-million dollar settlement
>   she received on a defamation case

The paragraph contains a datetime inside. My question is: how can I detect this date time inside paragraph and replace this with blank the datetime and the paragraph is dynamic so I know only format not the datetime exactly

Answer (score 2):

Go with Regexp. Find 4 digits, dash, 2 digits, dash 2 digits and so on...

```
$re = '/\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*/';

$str = 'Rebel Wilson hits out on Twitter after Bauer Media appeal defamation settlementImage:MediaPunch/REX/ShutterstockBy Gianluca Mezzofiore 2017-10-09 10:29:36 UTC The battle is not over for Rebel Wilson.The Pitch Perfect star has to face another legal challenge as Bauer Media is appealing against the multi-million dollar settlement she received on a defamation case';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

You will get the following result:

> Rebel Wilson hits out on Twitter after Bauer Media appeal defamation
>   settlementImage:MediaPunch/REX/ShutterstockBy Gianluca Mezzofiore UTC
>   The battle is not over for Rebel Wilson.The Pitch Perfect star has to
>   face another legal challenge as Bauer Media is appealing against the
>   multi-million dollar settlement she received on a defamation case

https://regex101.com/r/iVvs91/2

Comment: Thnx for your reply this work for me. can we remove UTC and all kind of date format like 10/12/2017 10:12:12 and if there only date no time like 10-12-2017 or 10/12/2017

Comment: If you want a solution for all date formats, you will need to write many parsers. Date formats are plenty... `Ymd`, `Y-m-d`, `m-d-Y`, `d/m/Y`... Not really a one solution fit's all.

Comment: Yes i know it will take many parser.But if there is any common approach for all you know please tell me. i want a common function which detect datetime from a paragraph and replace with blank.

Comment: Well.. there's this: https://github.com/etiennetremel/PHP-Find-Date-in-String but I have not a clue whether it works at all (just googled it)